# Could this pattern be used as the base for algorithmic trading?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

There is the pattern in the historical NYSE data (2019 - 2021M10) that I
found. If certain conditions are met then in more than 75% of cases the
close bid price of the share XYZ at 9:30 is at least 0.07% higher than
the close bid price at 16:00 the day before. There is a bit less than 60
seconds between the moment when it is clear if the conditions are met
and the close bid price. These conditions are met on more than 50% of
days. Let’s assume that the pattern will continue in the future. First of
all I am not sure if this information is useful at all. The pattern is there,
but the volume related to the close bid is between 100 and 5000 which
seem to be low. The share price has three digits (lower end).

Could this historical pattern be used as the base for algorithmic
trading?

- If this is the case then what would be the best trading strategy to
  achieve the highest expected profit (let say taking the next 6 months
  into account).
- If it is not the case then why.

I'm new to this topic, so forgive me if what I'm writing doesn't make
sense. If it is the case please let me know at which point (or points).

Comment: It is interesting, but it seems (to me) a small amount. So it remains to be seen if it can overcome transaction costs.

Comment: @noob2 Your point seems right to me. 
Actually this pattern was found by an application that I wrote. It could search for patterns regarding a different variable to increase the potential trading volume. Low bid price (one minute bar) seems to be a good candidate as it could mean that there is demand for the whole volume at this price. What you think?